# What exactly does HealthVault's WebApplicationUtilities.GetPersonInfo( authToken ) need to function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, healthvault

I am running in circles. I am using the HealthVault SDK (latest from NuGet) with our ASP.NET MVC application. My goal is to authorize our HealthVault application with a user, retrieve their PersonID and RecordID and store them in our database. I am unable to obtain a `PersonInfo`.

First, as according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff803620.aspx#AUTH I am redirecting the user to HealthVault to log in.

`https://account.healthvault-ppe.com/redirect.aspx?target=AUTH&targetqs=?appid={AppId}%26redirect%3d{ReturnUrl}`

I am successfully being redirected, I authorize my record and the app, and I am redirected back.

```
var target = Request.QueryString[ "target" ];
if (target == "APPAUTHSUCCESS") {
    var token = Request.QueryString[ "wctoken" ];
    var p = WebApplicationUtilities.GetPersonInfo( token );
}
```

The above code fails. Thrown on the line `var p = WebApplicationUtilities.GetPersonInfo( token )`.

> Microsoft.Health.HealthServiceAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.

The token isn't null, the application has all permissions AND it returns success, and yet Access denied is always thrown. What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In my case this happened when my private key from PFX file (configured in web.config) did not match public key for the application.
I'm still using test environment and use https://config.healthvault-ppe.com to configure my applications. 
Try extract public key (making .cer file) from your PFX file and upload it as a public key for the application.